# Local Function must declare a body because it is not marked 'static extern'

Tags: c#

Just need some assistance with an error I'm receiving. I'm attempting to combine two lists and display the result but am running into the Local Function must declare a body because it is not marked 'static extern' associated with the 'Merge' function.

```
        static List<int> Merge(List<int> list_a, List<int> list_b);
        {
            List<int> list_a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
            List<int> list_b = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5 };

            List<int> combined = new List<int>();


            foreach (int i in list_a)
            {
                combined.Add(i);
            }

            foreach (int i in list_b)
            {
                combined.Add(i);

            }

            combined.Sort();

            combined.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);   
            
        }
```

Comment: remove `;` from `List<int> list_b);`

Comment: This may be a bit advanced for you if you're learning but, for the record, you can do this: `var combined = list_a.Concat(list_b).ToList();`. You can even lost the separate sort call and do this: `var combined = list_a.Concat(list_b).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();`.

Comment: @Chetan It's still providing the same error.

Comment: I find it hard to believe it's giving exactly the same error when they stray semicolon is removed. Check again for the *specific* error message it's giving now.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - The error now is Merge(List<int>, List<int>)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: Then just put `return combined;` as the last line inside your method body.

Comment: @VanguardAnon That's another error, not the "same".

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Comment: Your last edit introduces new errors and invalidates the answers given. Since it is unimportant to the question in the title and the close reason, I rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

You have three issues in the method:

1. `;` after declaration
2. method's arguments should not be *redeclared*
3. you should *return* `List<int>` from the method

Code:

```
    static List<int> Merge(List<int> list_a, List<int> list_b) // no ; here
    {
        // You should not redclare list_a and list_b

        List<int> combined = new List<int>();

        foreach (int i in list_a)
        {
            combined.Add(i);
        }

        foreach (int i in list_b)
        {
            combined.Add(i);
        }

        combined.Sort();

        combined.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);   

        // you should return List<int> from you function
        return combined;             
    }
```

You can simplify the method with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

static List<int> Merge(List<int> list_a, List<int> list_b) => list_a
  .Concat(list_b)
  .OrderBy(item => item)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your method should return a List value. Your method never returns anything.

Add `return combined;` at the end of your method or make your method a `void`

Comment: When I include the return combined; nothing is printed.

Comment: Where have you added the return statement? You want to return after you call `combined.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`. @VanguardAnon

Comment: combined.Sort();

                combined.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

                return combined;

            } That's what I've done, but it seems to not print anything to the console now.

Comment: Are you calling the Merge method at all?